# To what extent are semiconductors used in high voltage and power grid electronics?

Tags: power-electronics, high-voltage, power-engineering

I'm thinking of silicon controlled rectifiers and HV thyristors. Why have vacuum tubes been phased out or have they? I believe that in some countries, power grid electronics is entirely tube-based because of their superior electrical robustness and vastly lower sensitivity to electromagnetic interference(in form of EMP attacks or geomagnetic storms).

Comment: The internet does not support you beliefs.  About the only area tubes are still used is in high power radio/radar transmitters.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Tubes are also widely used in guitar amplifiers and other musical electronics.

Comment: What "beliefs" are unsupported by the internet?

Comment: It's probably more about cost (most things are dictated by cost). If it works, why change? Well the new shiny technology might save money (more efficient) but if you can't afford to make the change then the change wont happen until you have to.

Comment: Solid-state tends to be far more efficient (provides you stay out of the MW-MHz realm, in which case tubes reign supreme (in which case they can be as big as washing machines). But for grid-connect stuff, solid state electronics better lend themselves to scaling, that is, you want to go from a 230kV DC-AC inverter to a 1000kV inverter? Stack up more thyristors... done, bit harder with tubes. Some thyristors are pretty tough, ABB has some puck models that will handle nearly 200'000 amps for a millisecond or so.

Comment: Thanks sam. I am aware that solid state is much more energy efficient at low voltages. One of the big disadvantages of solid state is its lack of electrical robustness compared to that of tubes.

Comment: It will be interesting to see how field emission tubes compare with solid state high voltage devices in terms of energy efficiency.